# select a specific record in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i am using CakePHP 2.3. I have a problem in my search query:

```
$this->loadModel("names");
    $modelMerge = $this->names->bindModel(array
    (
        'belongsTo' => array
        (
            'origins' => array
            (
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'joins' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array
                (                                                                'names.Name LIKE' => '%'. $search . '%',
                )
            )

        )

    ));
    $this->set("names", $this->names->findAllByName('$search'));
```

The result is empty - find('all') works fine but there is a problem with this code.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329043/how-to-do-pagination-in-cakephp Why spamming here - and that with multiple accounts? Start reading the documenation, that is far more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the cake document first.

model can't be plural. You have to set name of your model Name not names.

```
$this->loadModel("Name");
$names = $this->Name->find('all', array( // 'all' or 'first'
          'conditions' => array(
                 'Name.name LIKE' => '%'. $search .'%'
          )
));

$this->set(compact("names"));
```

Answer (score 0):

for Specific record you need to find it by primary_key. so if pk is "id"
the

```
$names = $this->Name->find('all', array(
      'conditions' => array(
             'table.id' => '".$id."'
      ),
      'limit' => 1
));
```